# How to create android cordova image upload with another input form

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, cordova, html-framework-7

I'm setting up a new application using `Cordova` and `framework7`, and I want to create a form containing `photo/image-from-camera` and input form as description and `name-file`.

I have successfully call camera function to take a picture from android phone, but I need to send image temporary location from phone to input value and submit form.

So where do I start to submit form with image data, name and description when I clicked submit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(cameraSuccess, cameraError);

// success
function cameraSuccess(file_uri) {
  window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(file_uri,
    function(fileEntry) {
        // fileEntry will have file name and file native URL
    });
}

// error
function cameraError(imageData) {
  // on error
}
```

> Make sure camera `destinationType` is set to `FILE_URI`